# i cant get my cron command to work

Tags: cron

I'm new to my VPS and i'm trying to set up a cron script this path use to work on my last account but it now come back with an error

```
/usr/bin/lynx -dump http://www.urllgoeshere.com/cron/email.php > /dev/null
```

the urls work fine as does the script i'm guessing there is something wrong with

```
/usr/bin/lynx -dump
```

how do i correct this where do i get the right information

please help

Comment: Is `cron/email.php` on your file system?

Comment: Does your VPS have lynx installed? And what is the error?

Comment: cron/email.php is on my files system and lynx is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `wget -q http://www.domain.com/script.php -O /dev/null`